# How can I use custom Input Components (Widgets) in forms of other Components?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to build a **widget library**, to use customized elements in my Angular Application. One of those widgets is an input-text.component. A styled input field.

**input-text.component.html**

```
<div class="co-container">
    <input type="text" [name]="in_name" [placeholder]="in_placeholder" [value]="in_value">
</div>
```

**input-text.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-text',
  templateUrl: './input-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.scss']
})
export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('co_placeholder') in_placeholder: string;
  @Input('co_value') in_value: string;
  @Input('co_name') in_name: string;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I want to use this input-text.component in a login.component.

**login.component.html**

```
...
<div class="row ">
        <div class="offset-4 col-4">
            <app-input-text co_name="username" co_placeholder="Benutzername" co_value="" [(ngModel)]="user.username" ></app-input-text>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
        <div class="offset-4 col-4">
            <app-input-text co_name="password" co_placeholder="Passwort" co_value="" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></app-input-text>
        </div>
</div>
...
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@core/mockup_user';
import { AuthService } '@core/authService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = {username: '', password: ''};

  constructor(private auth: AuthService){}

  login(){
     this.auth.login(this.user.username, this.user.password);
  }
}
```

But unfortunately **[(ngModel)]** can't identify  or at least can't find the value and name attribute of the input.component. The error code is as follows:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

How can I fix that? Or is there maybe a better way to insert input elements into forms of other components?

Comment: By putting `[(ngModel)]="..."` on `app-input-text` angular is expecting `app-input-text` to have implemented the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface

Comment: But there is already the [(ngModel)] on <app-input-text>. The line in html is as follows:
`<app-input-text co_name="username" co_placeholder="Benutzername" co_value="" [(ngModel)]="user.username" ></app-input-text>`

Comment: Please re-read my comment. [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a form control element. `app-input-text` is not a form control element. Thus angular is expecting an accessor hence the error.

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsaesc) is a bare bones demo

Comment: This information is very precise and userful. Thank you very much for this great answer. I will try to implement it.